# Bash Script - Expand ESCAPED dollar-sign ($) into its Variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables, variable-substitution

### My Problem

I have this `run.sh` script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=$(date)
FILE="my_file.txt.\${TODAY}"
```

---

When I echo `FILE` I get this:

```bash
echo ${FILE}

Output: `my_file.txt.${TODAY}`
```

---

But I want this:

```bash
echo ${FILE}

Output: `my_file.txt.15032023
```

### My workaround, but there has to be something better

```bash
eval echo ${FILE}

Output: `my_file.txt.15032023`
```

Comment: And you can't have `FILE="my_file.txt.${TODAY}"` in the assignment already?

Comment: ` \\` is use to remove special meaning from `$`, juste remove the removng symbol to get back to normal ;)

Comment: @Archemar No sadly the dollar-sign ($) is escaped and I can't change it^^

Comment: You can't change it? Why? If you want the `date` command to produce `15032023` for today's date, then you _need_ to change the script, because that's not what `date` produces without options.  When you make that change, you may remove the backslash while you're at it.  Please update the question with the context that is _clearly_ missing.

Comment: "_sadly the dollar-sign ($) is escaped and I can't change it_" - presumably then you can't amend the script, so in that case there's no point offering help because you won't be able to apply any of the suggested solutions

Comment: Writing a new script that you _do_ have control over would be one solution. You could use a copy of the existing script as a starting point.

Comment: `eval echo ${FILE}`?

Comment: @roaima what in the world?? Why is stackoverflow like this... There is a simple question and why can't you just answer that? I can change the script however I want, just the dollar sign has to be escaped! It's not that difficult to understand >:(

Comment: @Kusalananda yeah okay this is on me. You are right, my date command was simplified to make it look a bit simpler to understand. I thought it was clear from the question that this has nothing to do with the date command and I didn't see the need to include my whole date command. But that's on me, you are right, that's my bad^^

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are after:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

TODAY=$(date +"%d%m%y")
FILE="my_file.txt.${TODAY}"

echo "${FILE}"
```

And then `./run.sh` produces:

```
user@wang$ ./test.sh 
my_file.txt.150323
```

Comment: Note that they wanted the full year, and that you may use `printf -v FILE 'my_file.txt.%(%d%m%Y)T' -1` to assign to `FILE` without using `date`.

Comment: [Don't use UPPER case variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Comment: @tomp thanks for the answer, but please read the question carefully. This isn't about the `date` command, and you can't just remove the escaped dollar sign ($), it is there intentionally ^^

Comment: @Pixelbog The question gives no indication that you can't remove the backslash.

Comment: @Kusalananda omg I hate stackovetflow. The pure toxicity here is crazy. No Indication?! Its literally in the question! >:(

Comment: @Pixelbog This is not StackOverflow, it's the Unix & Linux StackExchange site. The fact that you can't remove the backslash or modify the script in any way is mentioned at some point in a comment thread, but it's not mentioned in the question. If you want it to be part of the question, then move it into the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda I meant every stackexchange site... I can do whatever  I want with the Script, change every letter, do whatever I want. ITS ABOUT THE ESCAPED DOLLAR SIGN. Cmon man it's not that difficult... :(((

Comment: @Pixelbog So delete the backslash.

Comment: @Kusalananda FR?... Fine if you want see it, here with REMOVED BACKSLASH: `'filename.${TODAY}'`... Happy now? And you CAN NOT remove Single quotes

Comment: @Pixelbog Why did you replace the double quotes with single quotes? The code you're showing in the question has double quotes. I think it would be better if you clarified your actual question. In comments, you seem to sometimes say you can change the script and sometimes that you can't. The fact hat you haven't accepted one of the answers shows that we still don't know what you mean.

Comment: Because in Bash single quotes let you preserve the literal characters. I simple have a string with an ESCAPED Dollar Sign `\$TODAY` and when I use it in Bash, it just prints out `$TODAY` but I want the value of `$TODAY`...

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always do the replacement manually with `${var/pattern/replacement}`:

```
$ FILE='my_file.txt.${TODAY}'
$ TODAY=123456
$ FILE="${FILE/'${TODAY}'/$TODAY}"
$ echo "$FILE"
my_file.txt.123456
```

Or, `"${FILE/'${TODAY}'/$(date +"%d%m%Y"}"` to get the date the format you show, as I think the default output format of `date` is different.

Opinionated sidenote: you might want to consider using dates like `YYYY-MM-DD` or `YYYYMMDD` instead, as they make the dates sort in the correct order more easily.